# Concatenate each column value into a string for a subquery

Tags: string, subquery, concatenation, coalesce

All I've done a lot of background reading on this on and off for the past day or so and I'm none the wiser on how to achieve this.

I have looked on this site and found ways of concatenating multiple rows into one column however what I'm after is a bit more bespoke, please help...

I have two tables - one is a list of people and details about them such as name etc and a person reference.

The second contains a number of alerts about a person, one person can have multiple alerts. This would contain a person reference and the type of alert they have in a string.

I want to join these two tables using an inner join on the person reference.
I next want to find all of the alerts for each person and concatenate it into a string and show this as the "All alerts" column.

So I will end up with the following output:

```
First Name | Surname | All Alerts
-----------+---------+--------------------------    
Tony       | Stark   | Alert 1, Alert 2, Alert 3
```

I can get as far as going through all of the alerts in the alerts table and put the alerts for every person into a string, obviously I need a concatenated value for each person, and haven't figured out how to do this.

I've spent a day on this and looked into XMLPath solutions and using CTE, CROSS APPLY and subqueries to specify the where clause. I am a little lost.

```
DECLARE @ConcatenatedVals VARCHAR (255)

SET @ConcatenatedVals =
    (
        DECLARE @AllAlerts VARCHAR(8000) 

        SELECT @AllAlerts =  COALESCE(@AllAlerts + ', ', '') + personAlert
        FROM Alerts

        SELECT @AllAlerts AS 'All Alerts'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this posted here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#Toc205129480

This referenced a solution by Adam Machanic

Also, stuff is actually a function, not seen this before:

SELECT p1.CategoryId,
       stuff( (SELECT ','+ProductName 
               FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p2
               WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId
               ORDER BY ProductName
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
            ,1,1,'')
       AS Products
      FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p1
      GROUP BY CategoryId ;